# Upper bounding the start of a distribution's CDF, given bounds on first moments

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, it.information-theory

Take nonnegative random variables $X$ whose first $K$ moments have bounds:

> $\mu^k\leq E[X^k]\leq c\mu^k$ for each $k=1,\dots,K$.

In this case what is an upper bound for $P(X\leq O(\mu))$?

---

I am aware of a paper[1] that states the result that the least upper bound is given by the coefficients, but the formula given is very complicated and depends on the exact moments.

[1]: [Bounds on a Distribution Function when its First n Moments are Given](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177728977)

Comment: Example: For $K=4$ and a lognormal distribution $X$ whose log is $N(1,1/2)$, (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=moments+of+LognormalDistribution%5B1%2C1%2F2%5D), we can take $\mu=e^{9/8}$, $c=e^{3/2}$, and we're looking for bounds on probabilities like $P[X\le\mu]=P[N(1,1/2)\le 9/8] = \Phi(1/4)$ in terms of $\mu$ and $c$.

Comment: What is the connection to information theory? And what is the context which makes it natural to use $\mu^k$ as a lower bound, without any coefficient on that term? The equation in the post forces $c \ge 1$, in which case it is trivial that "the least upper bound is given by the coefficients", in the sense that any probability is less than $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at:

[Moment information for probability distributions, without solving the moment problem, II: Main-mass, tails and shape approximation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037704270800513X)

P.N.Gavriliadis et al., Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics 229(1), 2009